# Typescript: Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I have disabled **comma-dangle** for array in my `eslintrc` config as follows:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": ["airbnb-typescript", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "import/newline-after-import": ["error", { "count": 1 }],
    "lines-between-class-members": "error",
    "newline-before-return": "error",
    "quotes": ["error", "single"],

    // here
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      {
        "arrays": "never",
        "objects": "always",
        "imports": "never",
        "exports": "never",
        "functions": "never"
      }
    ],
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["config", "public", "scripts"]
}
```

This is my **array**: `const foo = [1, 2, 3];`

**VS Code** doesn’t highlight any error to add a trailing comma to the last element of `foo`, whereas Typescript fails to compile with this error: **Missing trailing comma  comma-dangle**. For some reason, **Typescript** is not able to follow rules written in my `.eslintrc` config.

**tsconfig**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

The project is created `create-react-app` typescript template. Can you guide me with what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two tools in play here:

- ESLint (a *linter*): runs a configurable list of rules. Each lint rule checks for one particular problem and might report on instances of the problem it finds.
- TypeScript (a *language*): lets you write code in a syntax that includes all of JavaScript plus some new constructs for types. It includes a type checker that warns you if some code has mismatched types.

TypeScript doesn't know about your lint rules. So changing your "TSConfig" (`tsconfig.json` file) around won't help with this `comma-dangle` issue. Only the ESLint config file is relevant right now.

When I try the `comma-dangle` settings in the post, they report no violations - as expected. [[typescript-eslint playground with `comma-dangle`](https://typescript-eslint.io/play#ts=5.3.3&fileType=.tsx&code=MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDaBGANDATDgZgF0BuAKCA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQMYHsBbQgQwFoATEgOwHMl0wBtcbHRaafaSAGlbZY22SCU4kAnqgyRqiAG4c%2BA4ZHwAjAFaJcAF2lQS8AO6TU-YSICWhAA7d9jWQqUXLURAA970RzLmKPG6WkABmsNR6VvjUBs6BkCoQAL4qALqsqclAA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false)]

The way you're running ... *something* that's providing the `comma-dangle` lint complaint must be the issue. Make sure other tools are looking at the same ESLint configuration.